# Tomcat 8 package in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: tomcat

Do you plan to include Tomcat 8 package in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? If yes, when?

Comment: Somebody already requested a backport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/trusty-backports/+bug/1423781. You can also try to backport it yourself with the template instructions in the bug report.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not the way Ubuntu handles software. 14.04 was created with Tomcat 7 and shall remain that way. It will never be included in the default software of 14.04. Tomcat 8 was included in Utopic = 14.10.

If you want newer software in 14.04 you will need to install it yourself by [downloading](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) the installation software from the Apache site. There are [lots](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04.html#axzz3UdPP4qpm) of [tutorials](https://www.howtoforge.com/tomcat-on-ubuntu-14.04-install) on [how](https://iqbalnaved.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/installing-apache-tomcat-8-0-5-on-ubuntu-14-04/) to do this.